# Evaluating the integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\ln|x|e^{-x^2}dx$

Tags: integration, contour-integration, residue-calculus

Here's the problem.

> Evaluate the definite integral $$I:=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\ln|x|e^{-x^2}dx.$$

I have made some good progress, but I'm unable to complete the solution. Here's what I've done: obviously, the integrand is even, so we can rewrite the integral as
$$ I = 2\int_0^\infty\ln(x)e^{-x^2}dx.$$
Now, introduce the parameter $t$ and define
$$ J(t) := \int_0^\infty\ln(xt)e^{-x^2}dx \implies I=2J(1).$$
Differentiating under the integral sign with respect to $t$, we have
$$
\begin{split}
J'(t) & = \int_0^\infty\partial_t\ln(xt)e^{-x^2}dx\\
& = \int_0^\infty\frac{x}{xt}e^{-x^2}dx\\
& = \int_0^\infty\frac1te^{-x^2}dx\\
& = \frac1t\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2}dx\\
& = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2t}
\end{split}
$$
and therefore
$$ J(t)=\int J'(t)dt =\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\ln(t)+C. $$
It almost seems like we are done, since just plugging in $t=1$ should give us the answer. However, I have no idea how to find the constant of integration $C$. The usual values $t=0$ and $t\to\infty$ don't work, since the $\ln(0)$ in the integrand tends to $-\infty$ and $\ln(t\to\infty)$ goes to $\infty$. Any other finite value of $t$ seems unhelpful as well. Could someone help me complete my solution or offer a different method?

Comment: The solution should be $$-\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\pi } (\gamma +\log (4))$$

Comment: How did you obtain that?

Comment: Since the integrand is even, I'd say $\;I\;$ is $\;2\;$ times, and not $\;\frac12\;$ , that integral...

Comment: Yes, you are right. I have amended the question.

Comment: I found it in an old Notebook of mine.

Comment: I think that the constant C is I/2 because J(1)=I/2=C

Comment: The $C$ that you are trying to find is precisely the value of the integral you're trying to find (or rather, one half of it), so I don't think that this method is fruitful.

Comment: @Federico, I think you mean $C=\frac12I$. While that is correct, that doesn't help in solving the problem does it?

Comment: Infact I think that you can not solve your problem in this way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some different methods see [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/u380742h1655892).
You were close with that choice of parameter, however it doesn't lead anywhere
because your constant is the original integral (you just get back to square $1$).

Here is another approach, let $x^2=t$ to get: $$I=\frac12 \int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sqrt t e^{-t}\ln t}{t}dt$$ Now use the following [property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Evaluating_integrals_over_the_positive_real_axis)  , and the Laplace transform table to get: $$\mathcal{L}(\sqrt t e^{-t})= \frac{\sqrt \pi}{2} \frac{1}{(s+1)^\frac32}$$  $$\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left(\frac{\ln s}{s}\right)=-(\ln t +\gamma)$$
Thus we have: $$I=-\frac{\sqrt \pi}{4}\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln x +\gamma}{(1+x)^\frac32}dx$$
Evaluating: $\displaystyle{\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{(1+x)^\frac32}dx=2}\, $ is easy using that $$\int\frac{1}{(1+x)^\frac32}dx =-\frac{2}{\sqrt{1+x}} +C$$ And for $$\int \frac{\ln x}{(1+x)^{\frac32}}dx$$ Integrate by parts using the integral from above, but plug in the bounds only in the end to avoid convergence issues. Of course you can also consider: $$J(n)=\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{n-1}}{(1+x)^\frac32} dx=B\left(n,\frac32 -n\right)$$ Then differentiate once w.r.t $n$ and set $n=1$ to get: $\displaystyle{\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln x}{(1+x)^{\frac32}}}dx=4\ln 2$

Comment: That's great! One question, what is the function $B$ in the second method?

Comment: That is beta function: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function

Comment: I see. Thanks for the elegant solution! :)

Answer (score 0):

I'll tell you how Dr. Sonnhard Graubner probably got the answer. Since $\int_0^\infty x^t e^{-x^2}dx=\frac{1}{2}\Gamma(\frac{t+1}{2})$, $\int_0^\infty x^t e^{-x^2}\ln xdx=\frac{1}{4}\Gamma'(\frac{t+1}{2})$ and $I=\frac{1}{2}\Gamma'(\frac{1}{2})$.